# How to send an Object from java file to the mule flow message payload?

Tags: java, mule, esper

I am using Anypoint studio.
I have used esper CEP engine for event detection using java file. Once the event is detected i am getting output in the console from java file as system.out.println(Object).

I want the Obejct to be sent from java output to the mule flow either as a message property or payload, so I can store in MongoDB or I can reuse it for another event detection.
here is my flow:
[mule flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClRf.png)

Here I want the "event.getUnderlying()" Object to be sent to mule flow.

```
    public void  update(EventBean[] newData, EventBean[] oldData) {
                    EventBean event = newData[0];
                         obj=event.getUnderlying();
                                        
                            if(a2==0){
                            i++;
     System.out.println("Event received:"+i+" "+event.getUnderlying());
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Can you please add the section of your mule flow xml that describes how you are calling the java method from mule flow?

Comment: <component class="esper.Test_main" doc:name="Java"/>

Answer (score 0):

Just "post" to the input connector of the flow you want to send to. So for HTTP input use something like org.apache.http.client.HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection

(There are so many examples of how to use those on this site and many others...)

Other inputs have different libraries you can use, you could just save it as a file and have the file input pick it up. (depends on where you are deploying).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working as the UpdateListener class does not provide a return type of Object. I can't change from void to Object it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the Java class via Component (as you mentioned in your comment), your Java class **esper.Test_main** must be implementing Callable interface. More details on using Java component right - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/java-component-reference

In that case, you need to implement below method:

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) {

  //your code here

  return someObject; // return event.getUnderlying() in your case

}
```

The object returned from onCall() method is passed on as 'payload' to the next message processor in mule flow.

If you need to set a flow variable from the Java class:

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) {

  //your code here

  eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("variableName", "variableValue");

  return someObject; // return event.getUnderlying() in your case

}
```

Now, you will have a **flowVar** called *variableName* available in your mule flow.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am already getting the payload from flow to give its properties to the Esper Engine using Object Oncall function. Here the problem is that Oncall function is executing once on a single call of java class in the flow, but  it is possible that many events get created in each call (there are 30 esper patterns). I need each event to be sent to the mule flow once it is detected.

Comment: Yes. you can store multiple event objects in the flow variables as shown above. You can even store a collection of event objects in a single flow variable.